# Rsync specific files from a source to a destinantion with the same directory structure

Tags: rsync

i have a folder which has 1000 files in different folder and the file structure are different. I only need a list of specific files which i have in a list already. what rsync command do i use to copy only those specific files from the source to a destination.

the most important is to get the files in the exact folders from source to the destination